# Show hint over a CSS background image on mouse over

Tags: css

I'm using a `<span class="image">` with a background:

```
.image {
    background-image: url("image.jpg")
}
```

How can I also add a hint on this image when people put the mouse over it?

Is there a CSS way to achieve this?

Comment: No, but you can try the HTML `title` attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the HTML title attribute:

```
<span class="image" title="This is a hint.">
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something with `:after` content:

```
.image:hover:after {
    content:"This is a hint";
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fXuSB/

However, this content is probably better off in the HTML (and your image actually might be as well). You can use the `title` attribute for a simple default tooltip, or perhaps something like this:

```
<span class="image">
    <span class="hint">This is a hint</span>
</span>​​​​
```

```
.image .hint {
    display:none;
}
.image:hover .hint {
    display:block;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fXuSB/1/